# How to mock setting static class property in legacy Java code for JUnit 4 unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, static-members

I am writing unit tests using JUnit 4.13 and Mockito core 4.9.0. Following is a simplified version of the class being tested which is part of a legacy code that I don't want to refactor:

```
//JAR com.ibm.mq-8.0.jar
import com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment;
public class LegacyCodeToTest
  public void doSomething() {
    ...some other code
    MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "some-cipher-value";
    ...some other code
  }
}
```

Following is the unit test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestLegacyCodeToTest {
  @Test
  public void testDoSomething() {
    LegacyCodeToTest someVar = new LegacyCodeToTest();
    mock(MQEnvironment.class);
    when(MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite).thenReturn(null);
    someVar.doSomthing();
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the unit I am working with needs many other dependencies I cannot provide during unit testing and the line of code `MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "some-cipher-value"` or even just referencing `MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite` in the test is causing the run to crash due to missing dependencies which I cannot troubleshoot. I want to mock this line of code so that it has no effect as if it doesn't exist and I don't care about it during unit testing. Now I had to comment out this line to let it work.

Also, I know there is something wrong with the way I implemented mocking but I could not even reach that point since the test is crashing due to missing dependencies.

So, the bottom line is how I can mock such a line of code:

```
MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "some-cipher-value";
```

Mind you, I don't want to refactor the class as this will raise the need to trigger writing a lot of other unit testing and it won't be allowed.

Comment: It looks like that Mq dependency is hard coded. I don’t think there is anything you can do without making changes to the class. 

As a first step I would add a new constructor that takes the Mq decency as a parameter, move the code from the existing construct to the new constructor having the existing constructor call the new one passing it the hard coded value. That way existing code will work and we will gain more control in your test.

Comment: My above suggestion is not really a refactoring it is an addition.   If the team is uncomfortable you could duplicate the code from the original constructor rather than move, this is sub-optimal but perhaps safer.

Comment: Thanks, could you please add an answer with a sample of your suggested solution?

Comment: Having had time to properly read your question, I think you do not have much of a choice but to actually wrap `LegacyCodeToTest` in an interface.  Unless the code is using Records (Java 11+) then you are attempt to mock the assignment to a public property.  I dont think that is possible, you may be able to Spy on the assignment, either way you would need `MQEnvironment` to be injected during the test.  There is no indication in your example as to where the `MQEnvironment` would be injected, is it during construction or is it at the beginning of the `doSomething` method?

Comment: Please check this https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/8.0?topic=java-enabling-ssl-in-mq-classes. The class MQEnvironment has static properties and I'm finding it very hard how I can have the code in `doSomething()` to ignore the assignment
 `MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "some-cipher-value"`. This MQEnvironment class is referenced directly in that method. I'm not sure how to inject it. Can you suggest a sample?

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at the linked document I don't think it is possible to test `doSomething()` as it stands.
`MQEnvironment` represents the *global* environment for MQ, given that `doSomething` sets the values before it presumable then makes calls to `MQQueueManager` you are stuck with what is defined in `doSomething`.

In general when I find something is hard to test I feel I have made suboptimal design decisions.

Given this is a legacy system, I would introducing an interface to represent `LegacyCodeToTest` that way you give yourself a hook into the legacy code that will allow you to replace `LegacyCodeToTest` when you are ready.

If you are very lucky and `LegacyCodeToTest` is being passed into classes or methods you may get some benefits from using an interface such as simpler mocking as well.

If you are going to be doing a lot of work with legacy systems I am told (though haven't read it myself) that "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" by Michael C. Feathers is a good book to have by your side.

Anyway, a code example:

```
public interface CodeToTest {
   void doSomething();
   ... other method declarations as needed.
   ... if you are using Java 8+ new features of interfaces such as default 
   ... methods might be useful, but remember "with great power comes great responsibility" etc etc 
}

public LegacyCodeToTest implements CodeToTest {
    ... no other changes needed
}

public SomeClassThatUsesTheLegacyClass {

   // public aMethod(LegacyCodeToTest lctt) {
   public aMethod(CodeToTest lctt) {
      lctt.doSomething();
   }
}
```

This is a (small?) step in the right direction.
In the future you can introduce a better designed class to replace `LegacyCodeToTest` perhaps something like this:

```
public NewCodeToTest implements CodeToTest {
    private final String cypher;
    ... other MQ Environmental properties as needed.

    public NewCodeToTest(String cypher) {
       this.cypher = cypher
    }

    public void doSomething() {
       ...some other code
       MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = cypher;
       ...some other code
    }
}
```

This class is easier to work with as its collaborators/configuration are "injected" into the class at construction.
It still makes use of the `MQEnvironment` which I dont much like, so I would look to somehow abstract that or have a single API that deals with MQ, perhaps building it around or making use of JMS or AMQP.

This would be more or less my approach with the information I have to hand.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where is the unit test though? I think you gave me wonderful ideas and I still need to read it several times to digest what you provided. Was this the answer or part of the answer?

Comment: As I said, it looks to me like the Mq class is a global environment/context and it’s being manipulated in the method you are trying to test.  One possibility is that you can assert the values of the Mq class after you call `doSomething` as the only ‘output’ of `doSomething` as described will be side effects on other objects.